# how can i compile fdm fo my ubuntu machine?

Tags: compiling, source

how can i compile [freedownloadmanager](http://freedownloadmanager.org) for my ubuntu system?

from [this source](https://sourceforge.net/projects/fidmanager/files/source/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't, it is for Windows and requires Windows components to run. You would need to port the whole application. Here is an alternative ugetdm.com

[image]